# Expectation Failed when trying to update twitter status

Tags: c#, .net, twitter, oauth, dotnetopenauth

I can't seem to figure this one out. No matter what I do, I keep getting a "417 Expectation failed" error. Everywhere I've looked says that I need to get rid of the Expect header for the HttpWebRequest. Setting the static property `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false` or the instance property on the web request `request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false` never get's rid of the header. I have to manually set it to null to remove it.

No matter what though, I STILL get the 417 error. What am I missing?

```
private static readonly MessageReceivingEndpoint UpdateStatusEndpoint 
       = new MessageReceivingEndpoint("http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml", HttpDeliveryMethods.PostRequest);

public static XDocument UpdateStatus(ConsumerBase twitter, string accessToken, string message)
{
    var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    data.Add("status", message);
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false; //Doesn't work
    HttpWebRequest request = twitter.PrepareAuthorizedRequest(UpdateStatusEndpoint, accessToken, data);

    request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false; //setting here doesn't work either

    //request.Expect is still set at this point unless I explicitly set it to null.

    request.Expect = null;
    var response = twitter.Channel.WebRequestHandler.GetResponse(request); //Throws exception
    return XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(response.GetResponseReader()));
}
```

Comment: What do the headers look like? 417 is a specific reaction to an Expect: header, so if you're certain you're sending out none of those, that'd be really weird.

Comment: Right before calling GetResponse() the "Expect" property is null, and the headers collection does not contain the "Expect" header. I'll have to check with fiddler to see if somehow it's still getting put in there. I still can't explain why neither call to "Expect100Continue = false" is working

Comment: DotNetOpenAuth has 417 error handling built-in so that your app shouldn't even have to handle this case or set Expect100Continue to false.  Can you turn on logging so we can see if this is happening?  http://dotnetopenauth.net:8000/wiki/CodeSnippets/Logging

Comment: I might also venture to suggest that the samples that come with LinqToTwitter for DotNetOpenAuth itself don't have this problem.  Can you tell if you're doing anything different?

Comment: @andrew-arnott Yes I will turn logging on and get back to you. I'm not getting a direct 417 exception, it's being wrapped inside the DotNetOpenId excepetion (not sure what the ACTUAL exception the framework is throwing, but the 417 exception is the inner exception). I don't know anything about LinqToTwitter and would verture to guess I'm not using it. I copied the Twitter code from the ApplicationBlock in the samples and am trying to extend it to support updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DotNetOpenAuth doesn't set or support Except100Continue directly. Would be nice if there is a property in the Channel class.

Add this before your call to 'PrepareAuthorizedRequest':

```
    ((HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create
(UpdateStatusEndpoint.Location)).ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
```

Except100Continue is set depending on the called URL. So you can set it before the connection is created. You may even set it globally in the config file.

```
  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false" />
    </settings>
  </system.net>
```

Comment: DotNetOpenAuth just uses the HttpWebRequest class, so Eric, what is it that DotNetOpenAuth doesn't support about the Expect100Continue setting?

Comment: A perhaps cleaner way to set the Twitter's ServicePoint.Expect100Continue property would be `ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(UpdateStatusEndpoint.Location).Expect100Continue = false`

Comment: Andrew, I was thinking at the property: webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false; But after some rethinking, I assume, it doesn't matter. Both will probably contact the ServicePointManager.

Comment: It would be perhaps more obvious via webrequest.

Answer (score 1):

Set the Expectation to "expect:nothing" ..this is my code:

var data = new Dictionary();

data.Add("status", status);

HttpWebRequest request = twitter.PrepareAuthorizedRequest(UpdateStatusEndpoint, accessToken, data);

request.Expect = "expect:nothing";

var response = twitter.Channel.WebRequestHandler.GetResponse(request); exception 
            return XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(response.GetResponseReader()));

it worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

LinqToTwitter is a Twitter client library that uses DotNetOpenAuth.  I'll see about adding a message posting example to the DotNetOpenAuth core library for a future version.